# Why model validation is not working

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have following Model class that is used during the Web API Post. As you can see Id field is annotated as Required.

```
public class Model
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

The Post for API is as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Model value)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();

    Model newModel = new Model() { Id = value.Id };
    return Ok(newModel);
}
```

On a sunny day, this is what I see. All good

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtJBJ.jpg)

On a rainy day, when Id is not provided, I get following.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33IuM.jpg)

Given that in the second example, a Required field is not provided, shouldn't a BadRequest is returned rather than a 200 with invalid id guid with 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using the Required annotation

In the Web API Docs, your issue is known as 'under-posting'.

The issue is that `Guid` has a default value, so when no value is provided, it is initialized with the default value... which then satisfies the `Required` constraint.

To prevent this, counter-intuitively you make the `Guid` nullable using `Guid?`.

Then if the value is not provided, the deserializer will set the value to null, which will cause the `Required` constraint to be violated.

If the value is provided, it will be set, and all will be well.

See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api for more details, there is an example of a similar issue for a `decimal` property.

The key distinction to understand is that Guid.Empty is really a valid Guid.  The only way to distinguish between the user providing a Guid (which is empty) and not providing one at all is to make it nullable, so null = not provided, and Empty = the user provided the empty Guid.

### Using a Custom Annotation

If you really don't want to make your Guid nullable, you need to consider what would you do for a 'normal' value type, e.g. an integer.  Rather than making it required, you'd use a `Range` attribute and specify that it must be `> 0`.

Similarly for Guids, you'd ideally have an attribute that would simply test that it is `!= Guid.Empty`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#custom-validation for guidance on creating a custom validation atribute.

Comment: This means that all the required fields in the model should be set as nullable? yikes .... There got to be better way.

Comment: Updated to draw a distinction between Guid.Empty and not provided, and to offer an alternative solution

Comment: Thanks. Since my question is about .net core, does the techniques described in link about creating custom validation attributes apply to .NET core too?

Comment: Good point! Fixed the link to point to the aspnet core doco for the same stuff.  Looks the same, but the example is clearer I think.